# Meteor uploads file upload/download permission

Tags: meteor, file-upload, upload, permissions

I am building a notes functionality with attachments in it, I have been using [Meteor Uploads](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads) for file uploading. Everything works fine except for permissions. I have searched almost everything related to this but somehow I can not find a full example neither a clear answer.

There is an event shown below which is supposed to handle permission checks, but this does not run in fibre, so you have no access to collections and UserId

```
validateRequest: function (req, resp) {

}
```

**There are two issues I am trying to solve:**

1. Allow only the users that have permission to post notes, to be able to upload files.
2. A way to provide more secure file accessing

The first one would not exist as an issue if there was a way to call file start upload in server(As far as I know/tried it is only called in client).

```
Uploader.startUpload.call(Template.instance(), e);
```

I have made some security checks before uploading file(calling a server method) but that is in client. I have also added a cookie after opening the page which I then validate in server in order to make files not accessible out of app.

I have also read that permissions can be achieved by using tokens/secret keys as [mentioned here](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads/issues/58#issuecomment-87966554) but could not find a proper example.

**PLEASE NOTE**

Maybe the first issue is not a real issue in my scenario because I have permission checks when showing Note post ability but I wanted to know what is a good approach I could take.

Most important issue I believe is the second one regarding file access, what is a proper way to  serve files based on User permission? Also a good way to encrypt uploading file's name so that users do not access files by guessing the file name might be helpful.

Thank you guys!